# what security features a good Email Service Provider (for marketing) should have?

Tags: email, vendor-selection, requirements

To choose the right Email Service Provider (ESP) for e-mail marketing processes, what are security requirements and checklists that we should pay attention to and ask for from vendors?

In other words, what are security risks in an ESP implementation that we need to seek controls for ?

Comment: that will depend on the risks that are relevant to your company - else the generic cloud service provider questionnaire should suffice

Comment: I was hoping for more requirements specific to e-mail service risk. For example, shared IP used by the service providers for multiple companies, and then the IP being tagged as spam and affect all businesses.